insert into mySQL using Delphi ADOStoredProc
I have a mySQL with the following two tables:
person  keyed on ID
staff   keyed on ID and StaffID (used to link managers and their staff)
The following stored procedure should insert a row into the staff table provided both ID and StaffID exist in the person table
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM person WHERE ID = pStaffID) THEN
      INSERT INTO staff VALUES(pID, pStaffID, pDateOfEffect, pRemarks);
    END IF

The following code in Delphi should do the insert
procedure TfrmStaff.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (txtStaffID.Text <> '') then with DataModule1.ADOStoredProc1 do begin
    NullStrictConvert := false;
    ProcedureName:='Insert_Staff';
    Parameters.Clear;
    Parameters.CreateParameter('pID', ftInteger, pdInput, 50, ID);
    Parameters.CreateParameter('pStaffID', ftInteger, pdInput, 50, txtStaffID.Text);
    Parameters.CreateParameter('pDateOfEffect', ftDate, pdInput, 50, txtDateOfEffect.Text);
    Parameters.CreateParameter('pRemarks', ftString, pdInput, 100, txtRemarks.Text);
    ExecProc;
  end;
end;

I am using 43 and 45 as the two IDS, which both exist in the person table.  For test purposes I am leaving both txtDateOfEffect and txtRemarks empty.
This fails with the following error message:

check the manual for the right syntax to use near '{ call
Insert_Staff(?, ?, ?, ?)} at line 1;


isn't the syntax for using parameters in an SQL query ":parameter" => staff VALUES(:pID, :pStaffID, :pDateOfEffect, :pRemarks)

@PieterB, I'm using a stored procedure, the parameters are defined in that.  The stored procedure is working when I call it from within mySQL

Why did you omit the PL/SQL procedure's definition? With your Pascal procedure you didn't omit telling us its definition...

The first snippet of code is the stored procedure in the mySQL database, which is tested and working.  The problem i'm having is calling it from Delphi using the second snippet of code.  It's assigning the ProcedureName, adding the parameters and then trying to execute the SP.

No - it's just part of your stored procedure, not the stored procedure. A definition starts with CREATE PROCEDURE, just like in Pascal it starts with procedure and not if.

This is the sp
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Staff (
IN pID INT,
IN pStaffID INT,
IN pDateOfEffect DATE,
IN pRemarks VARCHAR(100))
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM person WHERE ID = pStaffID) THEN
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(pID, pSpouseID, pDateOfEffect, pRemarks);
END IF

From the definition you posted, it seems like your stored proc doesn't have any input parameters.

There are 4 input parameters pID, pStaffID, pDateOfEffect, pRemarks.  The stored proc is working in mySQL as typing CALL Insert_Staff(43, 45, null, null); results in the record being inserted

In the end I've decided to go with an ADOQuery instead of ADOStoredProc, using ExecSQL rather than ExecProc.  The following code works as expected (qAdd is an ADOQuery).  This allows me to continue using the stored proc on the server.
procedure TfrmStaff.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (txtStaffID.Text <> '') then with DataModule1.qAdd do begin
    Close;
    SQL.Text := 'Call Insert_Spouse(:pID, :pStaffID, :pDateOfEffect, :pRemarks)';
    Parameters.ParseSQL(SQL.Text, true);
    Parameters[0].Value := ID;
    Parameters[1].Value := txtStaffID.Text;
    Parameters[2].Value := 'null';
    Parameters[3].Value := 'null';
    ExecSQL;
  end;
end;


Try to put TAdoStoredProc on form or on data module, setup connection and proc name and call ExecProc method. If you get success, use parameters' settings from this component

Just tried that, same error.  Am wondering if it's even possible to run a stored proc from Delphi using ADOStoredProc and mySQL.  I've used this approach successfully with a MS SQL Server database, though.

I think firedac would be prefer for mysql. I use ADO only for MS SQL Server
